# APEX locked user is still able to login

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm facing troubles with APEX again! 
I create users for my application manually inside the application. I have a process lock_user, which is executed when a button is clicked and it should lock the user so he can not login to the application anymore. It seems to work, because in the 'Manage Users and Groups'-section the user is locked. Anyway, the user still CAN login to my application. I'm using the default login page.

Thats the code of my process:

```
BEGIN

UPDATE user
SET Status_id = '0'
WHERE user_id = :P45_user_ID;

APEX_UTIL.LOCK_ACCOUNT(p_user_name => upper(:P45_USERNAME));
commit;
END;
```

What could've went wrong?
Any solutions, tips or hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to enable the "Account Expiration and Locking" setting (in Administration -> Manage Service -> Set Workspace Preferences (visible to workspace admins)).
There is also a "Require User Account Expiration and Locking" setting that is only availale to instance admins. (Manage Instance -> Security -> Workspace Login Control)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of authentication are you using in your application? I would think that the locked accounts only work when using the built in Apex authentication.